# Add single quote to column in excel from script

Tags: python, excel, cell, single-quotes

hope you all doing fine, I have an issue with excel, because I create an excel document from a script in python, but I need a single quote ( ' ) in some columns of the document, but I don´t know how to do it:

I need to do something like this, in the formula bar is the value of the cell and before is a single quote, like this ( '0101 )

> COLUMN A

> 0101

> 0105
>
> 0106
>
> 0000

But then from Python I got the cell with the quote like this

> COLUMN A

> '0101

> '0105
>
> '0106
>
> '0000

Since is an bot automation script, I need to get the cell with the single quote from a script to apply in all the documents I generate.

Comment: not sure what your question is -- are you getting a single quote and you do not want it, or do you want to apply a single quote?

Comment: I want to apply the single quote to the column from a script in Python or something else

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to this / maybe I didn't understand your question but you can map a single quote to the beginning of every value in the column, ki nd of like this:

```
df["colA"] = df["colA"].map(lambda x: "'" + str(x))
```

Writing that column to Excel turns into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xRRu.png)

Comment: I think that´s exactly what I need, but I got a little lost, that code I put it in my python script? Or where? I´m using openxlpy to write the excel from python

Comment: Then you can apply the same idea to your situation, before writing the values to Excel, typecast to string if needed and then add the single quotes to the beginning.